# regexp for digits AND commas

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

This should be a lot easier than I think, but I've searching a trying for three hours now and nothing so here goes...
I have a varchar2(6) column, so it can hold anything.  I'm trying to make a regexp to find the value that have numbers **and** commas.  Anywhere.
I've tried:

```
'^\d{1,5}[,]\d{1,5}$'
'^\d+,+$'
'^[0-9]{1,}[,]{1,}$'
```

And a myriad of other combinations, nothing.  I also tried

```
'^,$'
```

Just to see what happened, and nothing.  There's plenty of combinations in the table like

```
1,2,
1, 2
1 , 2
,1
```

I am using syntax like:

```
where regexp_like (REPLACE(column_name, ' ', ''), '^[0-9]{1,}[,]{1,}$')
```

To strip out white space and lower the distinct values.

So can anyone point me in the right direction for a regexp to find values that are digits and at least one comma, in any order?

Update - 
Maybe this will clarify: I'm trying to find all values with at least one number and one comma. White space is irrelevant because I'm taking it out. No other characters than numbers and commas. The numbers and commas can be in any order.

2nd update - Due to unfamiliarity with regexp I was interpreting ^ as the start of the expression and $ as the end of the expression. As in everything between ^ and $ is the regular expression.  I just saw where ^abc means match on everything starting with abc and abc$ means match on everything ending with abc.

TIA

Comment: 1. - Why regex? Perhaps this can be done with regular string functions, would that be OK? 2. Can you state the EXACT problem you are trying to solve? For example: "I need a WHERE clause that is satisfied if and only if the value contains only digits, comma and/or spaces." I read your post a few times and I still don't understand EXACTLY what you need. **For example**: you said "at least one comma". ANYWHERE? Do you also need "at least one DIGIT"? Etc.

Comment: @mathguy - Second sentence: "...a regexp to find the value that have numbers and commas. Anywhere." So at least 1 digit and 1 comma, up to 5 of 1 and 1 of the other, in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a varchar2(6) column, so it can hold anything. I'm trying to make a regexp to find the value that have numbers and commas. Anywhere.

From that I'm assuming you want to find any strings that have at least one digit and at least one comma, in either order.

You can use `\d.*,` to find a digit followed by zero-or-more of any character then a comma and `,.*\d` to find a comma followed by zero-or-more of any character then a comma. Putting those two together gives the regular expression:

```
\d.*,|,.*\d
```

or, if you want to match the entire string (but it isn't necessary):

```
^.*\d.*,.*$|^.*,.*\d.*$
```

If you want to find strings that only contain at least one digit, at least one comma and any amount of white-space then you can replace each `.` wild-card match in the previous expression with `(\s|\d|,)`:

```
^(\s|\d|,)*\d(\s|\d|,)*,(\s|\d|,)*$|^(\s|\d|,)*,(\s|\d|,)*\d(\s|\d|,)*$
```

or you could negate the expression and test for not having any character that is not `,` or `0-9`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '[^,0-9]' );
```

Comment: The column can hold anything, I'm trying to find the columns with at least one digit and one comma, but no other characters.  I'm stripping out white space so that's not an issue.  So it could be  ,,,3 or ,3, or 123,3,.

Comment: @BigFish the final expression should work for you - if you have already stripped the white-space then you can remove the leading `\s|` from each capturing group. Or you can look for not having a non comma/digit character (see my update).

Comment: That's one of my issues with regex - it's really easy to negate something and to look for this OR that, but not simply this AND that...or so it seems...

Comment: @BigFish [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45991/1) Please provide an example that replicates the problem as I cannot get the same result as you.

Comment: Sorry mate, typo on my end...I copied your last example with the 'not' then changed it to try the other one and forgot to remove the 'not'.  Any rate, your 2nd to last (the long one) looks like it does the trick.  Thanks for that!

Comment: "Tried the other one" meaning this - `\d.*,|,.*\d`

Answer (score 1):

```sql
REGEXP_LIKE(column_name,'^[0-9 ,]+$')
```

This matches if the text contains exactly one or more digits, spaces, or commas.

`[0-9 ,]` means "any single digit, space, or comma". Adding the `+` after it turns it into "one or more digits, spaces, or commas". And the `^` at the start and `$` at the end means it must match from the start to the end - there cannot be anything else before or after the match.

Answer (score 0):

From your examples

```
1,2,
1, 2
1 , 2
,1
```

I infer (plus a bit of guessing):

At least one digit, optionally with prefix and/or postfix whitespace, and optionally commas before and/or behind. I guess ,1, would be ok too, as well as ,123 or 123, but 12 3, might not. The same for ",," (not valid).

```
",?[ \t]*[0-9]+[ \t]*,?"
```

This would be for a single number, maybe of several digits.

```
"(,?[ \t]*[0-9]+[ \t]*,?)+"
```

That would be multiple of that kind.

Depending on situation, a mark for Begin of expression (line) and end of expression (or line) might be neccessary or not:

```
"^(,?[ \t]*[0-9]+[ \t]*,?)+$"
```

I'm not used to the oracle regexp. in SQL. Maybe some parts need masking (the round parens, for example, and/or the plus signs). The whitespace is made from blanks and tabs (\t). If you don't need tabs, it's more simple:

```
"^(,? *[0-9]+ *,?)+$"
```

If one comma is mandatory, you have either decide, which, the first or the last, or create two alternative expressions, one with leading, one with trailing comma:

```
"^(,+ *[0-9]+ *,?)+$"    -- at least one comma before, violates ex. 1,2,3
"^(,? *[0-9]+ *,+)+$"    -- at least a trailing comma, violates ex. 2,3,4
"^((,+ *[0-9]+ *,?)+|(,? *[0-9]+ *,+)+)+$"
```

Sorry - can't test it.

Comment: Tab in Oracle is not `\t` anyway; you would need to hard-code it as chr(9) - meaning, with several string fragments concatenated with the hardcoded expression `CHR(9)`.

Answer (score 0):

MT0 gave me an answer that works, but after much more poking around I discovered this will also do the trick:

```
select count(*) as counter, my_column
  from my_table
 where regexp_instr (my_column, ',') > 0
   and regexp_like(replace(replace(my_column, ' ', ''), ',', ''), '[0-9])
 group by my_column
 order by counter desc;
```

Apparently my biggest problem, as I put in the updated question, was my misunderstanding of what ^ and $ are used for.  Hopes this helps others.

Thanks for everyone's help!